# "Authentication credentials were not provided." Django and AWS application

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-authentication

I'm implementing an web application in Django with a TokenAuthentication extension that I found here https://medium.com/@yerkebulan199/django-rest-framework-drf-token-authentication-with-expires-in-a05c1d2b7e05 (it's to set a time token expiration)

Everything works perfectly on localhost, but when I deploy my application to elastic beanstalk AWS  , the token that I send in the headers is not recognized. Is there a reason for this? I don't know if I am missing something, I have already tried many  corsheaders configurations but the answer still is
{
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}

Comment: which webserver are being used at AWS?

Comment: Hi, it's my first time using AWS.
I was guided by a tutorial to deploying Django application in Elastic Beanstalk:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/us_en/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Comment: The solution was to add the following in the .config file of .ebextensions:





container_commands:
  01_wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'

Comment: @AnaSánchez please add this as an answer. You won't believe the number of hours I wasted despite this being an issue I had ran into before.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution was to add the following in the .config file of .ebextensions: container_commands: 01_wsgipass: command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'**